# React Input Field not re-rendering/refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand why the input field is not refreshing.
The main idea is
There is a list containing some names and when the user clicks it, the card component below
is rendered with 2 things the name and an input field ( the value is set to the name )

**below explains what the code does...**

The state contains all the names and by clicking the add button more names are added to the list ( which is the state ).
There is another state which keeps the track of the current person.
Every name is rendered as a button (DOM_persons).
On clicking the person the currentPerson state changes.

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Card from './Card';

function App() {

  const [state,changeState] = useState(['Jerry'])
  const [currentPerson,changeCurrnetPerson] = useState(state[0])

  function addItem(){
    const names = ['Karren','Jesus','Wilfredo','Samuel','Chi','Kellye','Kazuko','Mae','Olevia','Ines']
    const newState = [...state]
    newState.push(names[Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length)])
    changeState(newState)
  }

  function changePerson(i){
    changeCurrnetPerson(state[i])
  }

  const DOM_persons = state.map((p,i) => <button key={i} onClick={()=>{changePerson(i)}} >{p}</button> )

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {DOM_persons}
      <Card name={currentPerson}/>
      <button onClick={addItem}>add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**this is the card component**
**Card.js**

```
import React ,{useState} from 'react'

export default function Card({name}){

    const [value,changeValue] = useState(name)

    function handleChange(e){
        changeValue(e.target.value)
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h4>{name}</h4>
            <input value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: In your Card component, you are not updating your original state. In other words, Card component does not send anything back to your App component. You don't need a new state in Card component. You can move your handleChange handler up to App component and pass it down to Card component as a callback. Then receive the input's value up in the App component and do your work with that.

Comment: The card component is a dummy component. The state that lives inside the card component has nothing to do with the main app component. The main problem is why the input field is not updating when the card component receives new props. The h4 is updated but not the input field

Comment: The card component can be a functional component. From the parent component, you can pass the changeinputfield function to the card component.

Comment: Because h4 takes its value from {name} props but input does not! Input's value and onChange handler are living inside your Card component.

Comment: Why are you managing state in your `Card` component? You can pass the handler (to receive new value from the `input`) and the `input` value as props from the `App` component. `App.js` should be the (single) source of truth.

Answer (score 3):

After experimenting for a while I got it, thank you for the support

( and it's weird to answer my own question.)

**Explanation**

The state inside the card component is created once( the card component is not unmounting ) so when the props get changed which is passed to the card component
won't affect the state of the card component because the state has already been created.
Now what I did to fix this is I added an useEffect hook that keeps the track of the props. So when the props change, the state of the card gets updated.
Kinda giving separate input field for every person.


**Code**

```
import React ,{useState ,useEffect} from 'react'

export default function Card({name}){

    const [value,changeValue] = useState(name)

    useEffect(()=>{
        changeValue(name)
    },[name])

    function handleChange(e){
        changeValue(e.target.value)
        console.log(e.target.value)
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <h4>{name}</h4>
            <input value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your components depend on different states. Your card component can be a stateless one and just take of what is being passed down to it. When you are using an internal state in the `Card` component it does render it with the correct value for the first time with `Jerry` however the consecutive changes made to the state in `currentPerson` is not handed down since it is not handle by your parent component.

**Parent Component**

```js
function App() {

  const [state,changeState] = useState(['Jerry'])
  const [currentPerson,changeCurrnetPerson] = useState(state[0])

  function addItem(){
    const names = ['Karren','Jesus','Wilfredo','Samuel','Chi','Kellye','Kazuko','Mae','Olevia','Ines']
    const newState = [...state]
    newState.push(names[Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length)])
    changeState(newState)
  }
    function handleChange(e){
        changeCurrnetPerson(e.target.value)
    }

  function changePerson(i){
    changeCurrnetPerson(state[i])
  }

  const DOM_persons = state.map((p,i) => <button key={i} onClick={()=>{changePerson(i)}} >{p}</button> )

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {DOM_persons}
      <Card name={currentPerson} handleChange={handleChange}/>
      <button onClick={addItem}>add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Card Component**

```js
function Card({name ,handleChange}){

    return(
        <div>
            <h4>{name}</h4>
            <input value={name} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This way changes made in your parent component will be reflected in your child component since it is a dependency of the parent component.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this is not what I want, the card component is just a dummy that only renders 2 things and h2 and an input field that contains the name of the person, the state of the card component has nothing to do with the App component. Changing the input filed doesn't do anything except changing its value.